# HTML display issues with Internet Explorer Browser

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to HTML/CSS and have developed this responsive web page. When you open in Chrome and make the browser window smaller, it works without issue. However, if you open this in IE and make the browser window smaller, the text jumps down in div.

You can do a "Page view source" and see both HTML and CSS. Please tell me what to do to fix this. The site is here: http://www.geocities.ws/testing123-789xr58/

Comment: There are always issues with IE.

Comment: what is the version of IE u are facing this problem with?

Answer (score 1):

In site.css, in the class from `.profiletilephoto`, make the height auto instead of the specified height.

You also have countless of the same classes all over the file, make sure you only include it once.

```
.profiletilephoto {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 15px;
    position: relative;
    width: 83.3333%;
}
```

Also, remove `overflow-x: hidden;` from html in the site.css file.

Comment: That worked!!  You're awesome!!  Thank you so much iBrazilian2.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to look at it and for suggesting changes, silverpenguin. I really appreciate both you and iBrazillian2's help.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at CSS Media Query to create a responsive website: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

You can also set the CSS of the element to a `min-width` so it would not be resized to a certain point.

**CSS**

```
.element { 
  min-width: 250px;
}
```